# ExtJS 5: Understanding Ext.data.field.Field.reference config properties

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm trying to understand what the [Ext.data.field.Field.reference](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Field-cfg-reference) configs do, as the names are a little awkward.  What I'm trying to do is have data that looks like this:

```
[{
  name: 'Mulder',
  state: 'Virginia',
  friends: [{
    name: 'Scully',
    type: 'partner'
  }, {
    name: 'Smoking Man',
    type: 'dad'
  }]
}]
```

And digest it using models, so I create them like this:

```
Ext.define('Agent', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: ['name', 'state']
});
Ext.define('Relationship', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: ['name', 'type', {
    name: 'agentId',
    reference: {
      type: 'Agent',
      inverse: {
        role: 'friends'
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

The reason I have inverse as an object on the Relationship model is because of [this thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?294626)... basically, I wanted my model named something differently from the retrieved data, so instead of a `Friend` model, I want it to be called `Relationship` and reference `friends` in the data, but all of that was undocumented.  After I solved that, I created my store ([test Fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nec)):

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  model: 'Agent',
  autoLoad: true,
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'data3.json',
    reader: {
      type: 'json'
    }
  },
  listeners: {
    load: function(store) {
      // outputs friends as a function and getFriends as null
      console.log('Agent', store.first().friends, store.first().getFriends);
    }
  }
});
```

So what I'm trying to do is have my getter method for friends be called `getFriends` instead of `friends`, but from looking at the documentation, I'm not entirely sure which config I use to specify this.  I've tried the ones that seem like the likely candidate (association, role, and inverse).  At this point, I'm pretty sure it's a property I set in the inverse object, but seeing as that's undocumented, I wouldn't know.

Previously, in version 4, we had the `hasMany` associations, but that seems to be getting pushed aside/undocumented in lieu of the `reference` way.  We would accomplish what I'm trying to do by adding this to the `Agent` model (please see [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nec) for working example):

```
hasMany: [{
  model: 'RelationshipHasMany',
  associationKey: 'friends',
  name: 'getFriends'
}]
```

Does anyone have any insight on how to name my getter?  Maybe you could also explain what the properties `association` and `role` do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `getterName`:

```
inverse: {
    role: 'friends',
    getterName: 'getFriends'
}
```

Comment: Awesome, yep, just figured this out as well... thanks Evan!  Is this anywhere in the docs, or is it something being worked on?  Also, will hasMany be going away?